# Excessive output size

Tags: python, math, analysis, set-theory

I wrote this code for my Real Analysis course's final project. It is a very basic calculator using the Von Neumann construction of the natural numbers. The problem I am having is that when I try to write the result to a text file, the file is excessively large for relatively small numbers. For example, when I try to compute 30*2=60 the .txt file ended up being over 25 gigabytes (it should be mentioned that my computer automatically terminated the process before it had concluded).

Using this construction numbers are turned into arrays and will get very large very very quickly. However a .txt file with the number 60 being over 25GB seems extremely large. Is there anything wrong with the code or is this just a consequence of the construction itself?

Here is the code:

```
sol = []

a = 30
b = 2

sol = multiplication(set[a], set[b])
for i in range(len(sol)):
    print(sol[i])
    print('\n')

print(len(sol))
```

The "set[a]" and "set[b]" takes a number a and b and converts them using the construction of the natural numbers. That can be seen here

```
emptySet = []
set = [emptySet]

for i in range(1000):
    emptySet = emptySet + [emptySet]
    set.append(emptySet)
```

And then multiplies the two numbers like so

```
def multiplication(x, y):
    if x in y:
        return multiplication(y, x)
    if y == []:
        return []
    hold = []
    if len(y) == 0: return []
    elif len(y) == 1: return x
    else:
        for i in range(len(y)):
            hold = addition(hold, x)
        return hold
```

Which uses this addition function

```
def addition(x, y):
    if x in y:
        return addition(y, x) # n1 > n2
    if y == []:
        return x
    x = x + [x]
    y = y[-1]
    return addition(x, y)
```

I felt compelled to add all the relevant code since I am not too well versed with programming. Thank you!

Here is a Wikipedia article for more information about how the natural numbers are constructed using the method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers

Comment: where is the code that creates a file?

Comment: I printed it to the file using the command line so "python3 [fileName].py > [fileName].txt"

Comment: @Z0S0 And what is the output of `python3 [fileName].py `?

Comment: It outputs the representation of the result (in the example above, the number 60) using the con Neumann construction of the natural numbers. So if my input is a=1 b=3 with the multiplication function, the output file would read “[[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]” if I got my brackets correct.

Answer (score 2):

The string representation of the nested lists you're using to represent your numbers grow exponentially. I suspect the file you're seeing with 5 TB is in fact incomplete, as the actual representation of 60 in that system would take more than 3 exabytes (3 million terabytes). It's likely that the computation of the larger numbers gets bogged down or crashes when your computer runs out of RAM (probably somewhere in the 40s) and you're only seeing the strings that were printed up to that point.

You can easily calculate how large the string representation of each number will be using this formula:

```
 def length_of_von_neumann_str(n):
     if n == 0: return 2   # we need a special case for []
     return 3 * 2**n - 2   # solved via the recurrence: L(n) = 2*L(n-1) + 2
```

An even more interesting question is why you don't run out of memory when *creating* the nested lists. The reason is that the same list object can be referenced many times in other lists. There's only one empty list object created (the initial value you initialize `emptySet` with), but it's contained in all of the other list objects (each created by the `+` operator later in the setup code). Indeed, there's only one list of each size, which gets referenced by all the larger lists. The nested list value `set[n]` only needs `O(n**2)` space for all the references, even though its string representation is `O(2**n)` characters long.

Comment: It only needs `O(n)` space for all the references, not `O(n**2)`, right?

Comment: Okay I understand. Thank you for the thorough response! I’ll play with this a bit more.

Comment: @DillonDavis: The list referenced by `set[n]` takes `O(n)` for its own references, but those references are to all the smaller lists. The total memory use for all the lists up to `set[n]` is `O(n**2)`.